# Посчитать кол-во чисел от start до end, кроме чисел содержащих цифру 5

Tags: javascript, математика

> Необходимо написать функцию counter, которая принимает в виде
> аргументов два числа: старт и конец. Функция должна возвращать число
> элементов массива между числами, за исключением числа, в котором
> содержится число 5. Стартовое и конечное число включается в число
> элементов массива. Результат может содержать число 5. Стартовое число
> всегда меньше конечного. Оба числа могут отрицательными.

Я решил это:

```js
function counter(start, end) {
  const arr = [];

  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    const find5 = String(i).split('').find(item => item === '5');

    if (find5 === undefined) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }

  return arr.length;
}

console.log(counter(1, 6));
```

Но хотелось бы это решить как-то более круто, одним каким-то математическим выражением, побитовыми сдвигами или что-то типа того, но я плохо мыслю так, прошу взгляда со стороны

Comment: делал когда-то давно подобную задачу на питоне - там весь смак в том, что диапазон дается в районе 10^50, т.е. обход через `for`  невозможен и надо решать по другому - типа сколько в диапазоне `10^n` - `10^(n+1)` таких чисел - и это всё задается обычными формулами

Comment: @Zhihar вот как раз как придумать такую формулу я вообще не понимаю, как такие формулы вообще можно выводить, как размышлять

Comment: начните с частного случая - диапазон от `0` до `10^n` - чтобы понять как это работает - рассмотрите от 10 до 100 и увидите, что надо выкинуть 10 чисел (5x) и надо выкинуть `9` чисел `15, 25, 35, 45, 65, 85, 95` - итого 18, дальше посмотреть, потом от `100` до `1000` и вы увидите формулу!!!

Answer (score 1):

Вроде именно эта задача (делал на питоне)

Посмотрите подойдет ли вам для JS:

```
def dont_give_me_five(start, end):
    def calculate(number, type):
        count = 0

        overflow = False
        digits = list(map(int, str(number)))

        for index, digit in enumerate(digits):
            digit = (9, 0)[type] if overflow else digit

            if digit == 5:
                digit, overflow = (4, 6)[type], True

            variants = digit if digit < 5 else digit - 1
            count += variants * 9**(len(digits) - index - 1)

        return count

    if start <= 0 and end <= 0:
        v1 = calculate(abs(start), False)
        v2 = calculate(abs(end), True)

        return v1 - v2 + 1
    elif start >= 0 and end >= 0:
        v1 = calculate(abs(start), True)
        v2 = calculate(abs(end), False)

        return v2 - v1 + 1
    else:
        v1 = calculate(abs(start), False)
        v2 = calculate(abs(end), False)

        return v2 + v1 + 1


print(dont_give_me_five(-123456789, 987654321))
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне стало интересно и я захотел сделать массивы чисел с 5 и без 5
Я сделал функцию nextNum(num, digit) - которая возвращает следующее число от num, в котором есть digit
И также сделал противоположную функцию --> notNextNum - возвращает следующее число, в котором нету digit.
Только вот придумать эффективную формулу для получения следующего числа с digit или без digit я не смог :(
Я просто рекурсией иду и увеличиваю на 1, тоже самый цикл

```js
function counterWith(start, end, digit) {
  const arr = [];

  for (let i = nextNum(start - 1, digit); i <= end; i = nextNum(i, digit)) {
    arr.push(i);
  }

  return arr;
}

function counterWithout(start, end, digit) {
  const arr = [];

  for (let i = notNextNum(start - 1, digit); i <= end; i = notNextNum(i, digit)) {
    arr.push(i);
  }

  return arr;
}

function nextNum(num, digit) {
  let totalNum = num + 1;
  const findDigit = String(totalNum).split('').map(Number).find(item => item === digit);

  if (findDigit === undefined) {
    return nextNum(totalNum, digit);
  }

  return totalNum;
}

function notNextNum(num, digit) {
  let totalNum = num + 1;
  const findDigit = String(totalNum).split('').map(Number).find(item => item === digit);

  if (findDigit !== undefined) {
    return notNextNum(totalNum, digit);
  }

  return totalNum;
}

console.log(counterWithout(0, 20, 5));
console.log(counterWith(0, 20, 5));
```